# Does Rails allow conditional validations for validates_associated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Does Rails allow conditional validations for validates_associated?  I'm seeing the following on Rails 4.2.0.  Am I trying to do it incorrectly?

**Models:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books

  validates_associated :books, if: :should_validate_book?

  def should_validate_book?
    return false
  end
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :title
end
```

The presence validation on Book's title attribute still runs (Rails console):

```
> u = User.create!
 => #<User id: 2, created_at: "2015-02-24 19:34:51", updated_at: "2015-02-24 19:34:51">
> u.books.build
 => #<Book id: nil, user_id: 3, title: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
> u.valid?
 => false
> u.books.first.errors
 => #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fa256b210d8 @base=#<Book id: nil, user_id: 3, title: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:title=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that validates_associated is ON by default for `has_many` relationships.  To make it conditionally, you'd need to add validate: false to the has_many declaration:

```
  has_many :books, validate: false
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails since time immemorial `validates_associated` has only taken [a list](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated) of attributes. Besides that, you'd kind of be mixing up behavior between your models from what I gather from the criteria you've pasted. A better approach would be to adjust your validations in the `Book` model to account for the variation and let `Book` decide for itself whether an object should be validated or not.

Comment: The code in the question was just a simple model I wrote to illustrate the behavior I was seeing with validates_associated, so I still think validates_associated is the way to go.  The page that you linked to shows the method signature `validates_associated(*attr_names) public`, which implies that it allows a single attribute.  Am I missing something? Thanks!